# Using a range sum with multiple cells and calculate & round before using the cell

Tags: excel, sum, rounding

I am having trouble with writing a query/fx for excel, I have a list of numbers which I need to add a percentage on top of that, after that I need it rounded and retrieve the total value of it.

I do not need to do that action on that item itself, I need to have that data so that I can retrieve the total value (after adding a percentage and rounding it with two decimals)

I do know know I can use "ROUND(A1, 2)" for rounding, or "Sum(A1:A10)" for retrieving the total. But I just cannot seem to find any way to modify the value(memory wise) before retrieving the 'new value' per cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROUND(A1:A10*(1+C1),2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! this was exactly what I was searching for. :)